# Copy Production SQL Server database into Test Database when they are synch (mirror) in availability databases

Tags: sql-server

My current set up is the following:

My Sugi and SugiTest database are mirrored.

[image]

I would like to know how to simply dump/copy production data/functions/procedures/... from my production database to my test database.

i.e. Overwrite my SugiTest database with Sugi database.

Comment: `Backup` and `Restore`?

Comment: It doesn't work since they are mirrored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove SugiTest database from availity group (in "Availability Databases" right click on SugiTest then click "Remove Database from availability group..."). Then restore it with Sugi backup. Put database in availity group, start sync with secondary.

Comment: I see. I will try this. Any way to automatize this process then?

Comment: You can create a script like this: 

ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP "group_name" REMOVE DATABASE [SugiTest];
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [SugiTest] FROM DISK = '.../Sugi.bak' WITH FILE = 1, REPLACE, ... ;
GO
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP "group_name" ADD DATABASE [SugiTest];

Comment: Works well. Thank you